# Activity crashed if we close it (back) before java thread completes the task

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I created a thread in Oncreate of an activity and then after the task ends then it makes changes to the UI of the activity. The task takes 5-6 seconds that's why I used the thread.

Here is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String folderSize = calculateFolderSize(); // my work 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(folderSize + " GB");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        
        thread.start();
```

Everything works fine, I start the activity then the size is calculated and then the textView gets updated and shows the size. It takes 6 seconds on average.

**The problem** - when I open the activity then the thread starts in the OnCreate method. If I press the back button before the thread completes then my application crashes in 6 seconds (when the thread completes its work).

What is the solution to this problem, is there any alternative or I need to stop the thread in back pressed in that activity.

Comment: post the error stack trace

Comment: Update from me (@Vijay), we should stop all threads in the onStop() override method. There is no need to run the process if the activity is closed because they are not going to make any changes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `runOnUiThread` code invokes after activity gets destroyed.

You should check if activity is destroyed:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String folderSize = calculateFolderSize(); // my work
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isDestroyed())
                            textView.setText(folderSize + " GB");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
```